# Maximo Control Desk (7.5.1.2) - Measuring business hours spent in a specific status

Tags: maximo

We're transitioning to a managed service provider for our IT service desk and deskside and we're working out the details of their SLAs.  Many of the SLAs are based on ticket status.  An example of this is the following:

"Measures the amount of time it takes to assess, schedule, test, and package application packages before they are available for User Acceptance Testing."

My first thought was to try using SLAs to measure this, as they neatly tie together calendars and priorities, but I'm having a really hard time finding any information about how I could do this.

Now I'm looking into using the TKSTATUS.STATUSTRACKING attribute on tickets, but I believe this just tracks straight 24/7 time instead of taking into consideration any calendars.

Has anyone tried this before?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

We are in a similar process, but we are measuring time on site of vendors for our work orders. Opposed to using any SLAs we have diffrent statuses which mark different events. Then when we want to know how long it took for an event to finish, we look to see the time required to change status in the wostatus table.

Comment: Unfortunately, we need to exclude non-working time (weekends, holidays, after-hours, etc) and can't just subtract one date-time from another to see how much time elapsed.